# I couldn't upgrade apache2 from 2.4.41 to 2.4.5 on Ubuntu vps

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, upgrade

I'm trying to use websockets on my website running on an apache2 (version 2.4.41) but since `mod_proxy_wstunnel` module is only available on 2.4.5 I guess I need an upgrade.

I tried this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And then ran `sudo apt-get install apache2` but no matter what I try it keeps saying `apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.41-1ubuntu1).`

Any chance I can upgrade to 2.4.5?

Comment: 2.4.41 is newer than 2.4.5.

Comment: oh my.. thanks for the heads up. Explains why when I try to enable the mod_proxy_wstunnel using a2enmod it works fine.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!